# Force a table <TD> to occupy the full vertical space?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, spfx

I want to show 3 boxes of content (Images + links ) inside a Table inside my SPFx react web part, here is the final result i have:-

[image]

I have the following code:-

`singlenews.tsx`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';
import NewsTableCell from './NewsTableCell';

export interface INews {
    recentNews: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featuredNews?: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featured: boolean;
}

export default class SingleNews extends React.Component<INews, {}> {
    public render(): React.ReactElement<INews> {

        const newsTableCells = this.props.recentNews.map((post, index) => {
            return (
                <NewsTableCell
                    post={post}
                    rowspan={index === 0 ? 2 : 1}
                />
            );
        });

        return (
            <table>
                {this.props.featured ?
                    <>
                        <tr>
                            { newsTableCells[0] }
                            { newsTableCells[1] }
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            { newsTableCells[2] }
                        </tr>
                    </>
                    : null
                }
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

`newstablecell.tsx`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';
import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';

export interface INewsTableCellProps {
    post: ISingleNewsProps;
    rowspan: number;
}

export default class NewsTableCell extends React.Component<INewsTableCellProps, {}> {
    public render(): React.ReactElement<INewsTableCellProps> {
        
        const { post, rowspan } = this.props;
        
        return (
            <td rowSpan={rowspan}>
                <a
                    className={styles.singleNews}
                    href={post.link}
                    key={post.Title}
                >
                    <div
                        className={styles.singleNews__image}
                        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
                    />
                    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                                {post.date}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                            {(rowspan===2)?
                            
                            <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title__featured}>
                                {post.Title}
                            </h2>
                            :                        
                            
                                <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                                {post.Title}
                            </h2>}

                            
                            
                            
                            {post.likes ? (
                                <div
                                    className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                                >
                                    <span
                                        className={
                                            styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                                        }
                                    >
                                        <Icon iconName='Like' />
                                        {post.likes}
                                    </span>
                                    <span className={
                                            styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__comments
                                        }>
                                        <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                                        {post.coments}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            ) : null}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        );
    }
}
```

`SingleNews.module.scss`:-

```
@import '~office-ui-fabric-react/dist/sass/References.scss';
@import '../../../../assets/global.module';

.featured {
  flex: 2;
}

.secondary {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

.singleNews {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: $font-family;
  font-size: $font-size;
  font-weight: $regular-font-weight;

  &__image {
    padding: 5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    &.featured {
      height: 75%;
    }
  }

  &__content {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: $white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid $medium-silver;
    border-top: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    &.featured {
      height: 25%;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    &__info {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: $regular-font-weight;
      color: $primary-font-color;

      &__title {
        font-size: 16px; //22px mob
        font-weight: $semiBold-font-weight;
        color: $primary-font-color;
        max-width: 290px;
        min-width: 135px;
        margin: 15px 0 0;
        word-break: break-word;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: -webkit-box;
        line-height: 23px; /* fallback */
        max-height: 46px; /* fallback */
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

        &__featured {
          font-size: 22px; //2.33 mobile
          font-weight: $semiBold-font-weight;
          max-width: 230px;
          margin: 15px 0 0;
        }
        &__first {
          font-size: 1.83em; //2.33 mobile
          font-weight: $semiBold-font-weight;
          max-width: 230px;
          margin: 15px 0 0;
        }
        
      }
      

      &__date,
      &__label {
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      &__reactions {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-self: flex-end;
        margin-bottom: 5px;

        &__likes {
          margin-right: 10px;
        }

        &__likes > i,
        &__comments > i {
          margin-right: 5px;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    &__content {
      &__info {
        &__title {
          max-width: 230px;

          &__featured {
            font-size: 1.83em; //22px mob
            min-width: 380px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above is working well, but I only issue I am facing is: how can I expand the first box (cell) to fully occupy the vertical space, as per the arrows I added to the picture?

Comment: Have you tried making it a flex and then giving it a height of 100vh ..??

Comment: @p4avinash i am not that expert in css ,, so can you provide a sample code please?

Comment: @JohnJohn Could you share your code in codesandbox?

Comment: @MajidM. thanks for the reply.. it is hard because this is a react sharepoint SPFx